# Harmonic forms for Complex Projective Space.

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hodge-theory, laplacian

For complex projective space with the Fubini-Study metric and associated Laplace-de Rham operator $dd^\ast+d^\ast d$. How does one find a concrete description of the space of harmonic forms? That is, how does one find a basis of the space of forms $\omega$ for which $(dd^\ast+d^\ast d)(\omega)=0 $?

Comment: Since the cohomology of $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$ is so simple,
I think the harmonic forms
 would just be multiples of the Kahler form and the constant functions.

Answer (score 10):

Let $X$ be a compact Kahler manifold with Kahler form $\omega$. Then constant functions are obviously harmonic, and if $\alpha$ is harmonic then so is $\omega\wedge \alpha$
because this operation  commutes with the Laplacian (see Griffiths-Harris page 115). 
When $X=\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$, $\omega^i$is
the sole harmonic form of degree $2i$, because it 
generates $H^{2i}(X)$.

**Footnotes**

1. Of course, I meant that $\omega^i$ is a basis for degree $2i$ harmonic forms.
2. There are no harmonic forms of odd degree, because there is no cohomology.
3. Curiously, this argument is valid for any Kahler metric on projective space, not just the Fubini-Study metric.
4. We can argue differently by noting the Fubini-Study metric is invariant under the action of $U(n+1)$, so the same is true for harmonic forms...

Comment: Does anyone know how to do an umlaut (and similar diacritics) on Mathoverflow? Writing K\"ahler doesn't seem to work.